# how to get records corresponding to all months in a year in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset :

```
Month   id1   id2  id3    value

Jan-17   1    2    3       67
Feb-17   2    3    4       43
```

How do I get the combination of `(id1, id2, id3)` corresponding to all  months in a year?

For eg . The output should look something like this :
If I start from jan-17 :

```
month    id1  id2  id3   value
jan-17    1    2    3     67
feb-17    1    2    3     0
mar-17    1    2    3     0
apr-17    1    2    3     0
may-17    1    2    3     0
jun-17    1    2    3     0
jul-17    1    2    3     0
aug-17    1    2    3     0
sep-17    1    2    3     0
oct-17    1    2    3     0
nov-17    1    2    3     0
dec-17    1    2    3     0
jan-17    2    3    4     0
feb-17    2    3    4     43
mar-17    2    3    4     0
apr-17    2    3    4     0
may-17    2    3    4     0
jun-17    2    3    4     0
jul-17    2    3    4     0
aug-17    2    3    4     0
sep-17    2    3    4     0
oct-17    2    3    4     0
nov-17    2    3    4     0
dec-17    2    3    4     0
```

Comment: You replicate `id1=1, id2=2, id3=3` from the first record to all other months? Why you have two jan-17 and two feb17? Please explain the logic for your desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Need more information. How many IDs are there?

Comment: Hi Guru !! there are multiple IDs .I just want each of the Ids to be present against all months

Comment: Only ID1 needs to be replicated?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate all months for a year with:

```
select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)
from dual
connect by level <= 12
```

And you can get all combinations of IDs with:

```
select distinct id1, id2, id3 from your_table
```

You can cross-join thos to get all ID combinations for all months:

```
select month, id1, id2, id3
from (
  select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
cross join (
  select distinct id1, id2, id3 from your_table
)
```

which gives you 24 rows from your sample data. Then you can left-join *that* to your table again to pick up any values, and use coalesce to use zero when there is no match:

```
with cte (month, id1, id2, id3) as (
  select month, id1, id2, id3
  from (
    select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1) as month
    from dual
    connect by level <= 12
  )
  cross join (
    select distinct id1, id2, id3 from your_table
  )
)
select cte.month, cte.id1, cte.id2, cte.id3, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from cte
left join your_table t on t.month = cte.month
and t.id1 = cte.id1
and t.id2 = cte.id2
and t.id3 = cte.id3
order by cte.id1, cte.id2, cte.id3, cte.month;

MONTH             ID1        ID2        ID3      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-01-01          1          2          3         67
2017-02-01          1          2          3          0
2017-03-01          1          2          3          0
2017-04-01          1          2          3          0
2017-05-01          1          2          3          0
2017-06-01          1          2          3          0
2017-07-01          1          2          3          0
2017-08-01          1          2          3          0
2017-09-01          1          2          3          0
2017-10-01          1          2          3          0
2017-11-01          1          2          3          0
2017-12-01          1          2          3          0
2017-01-01          2          3          4          0
2017-02-01          2          3          4         43
2017-03-01          2          3          4          0
2017-04-01          2          3          4          0
2017-05-01          2          3          4          0
2017-06-01          2          3          4          0
2017-07-01          2          3          4          0
2017-08-01          2          3          4          0
2017-09-01          2          3          4          0
2017-10-01          2          3          4          0
2017-11-01          2          3          4          0
2017-12-01          2          3          4          0
```

If you have combinations of IDs that only appear in other years and don't want those included you could limit it to only those that have *any* data in the specified year by changing the ID query to filter for that:

```
select distinct id1, id2, id3 from your_table
where extract(year from month) = 2017
```

or

```
select distinct id1, id2, id3 from your_table
where month between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-12-01'
```

I'm assuming `month` is a `DATE` column where all the values are midnight on the first day of a month. You can format that however you want for display of course.

---

As @boneist mentioned, since 10g we can use a [partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) instead of getting those IDs in a separate step:

```
with months (month) as (
  select add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12
)
select m.month, t.id1, t.id2, t.id3, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from months m
left join your_table t partition by (t.id1, t.id2, t.id3)
on t.month = m.month
order by t.id1, t.id2, t.id3, m.month;
```

which gets the same result:

```
MONTH             ID1        ID2        ID3      VALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-01-01          1          2          3         67
2017-02-01          1          2          3          0
2017-03-01          1          2          3          0
...
2017-01-01          2          3          4          0
2017-02-01          2          3          4         43
2017-03-01          2          3          4          0
...
```

but is much simpler (and more efficient as it only hits your table once).

Comment: I think a partitioned outer join could do away with the need to find the distinct ids

Comment: @Boneist - quite right of course... I'll add that, but will remove it if you answer yourself. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexPoole I \*love\* the partitioned outer join; it's an elegant solution to this type of problem imho!

Comment: @boneist - lol - I love it too, I finished writing the solution that way but you (and Alex) moved faster than me. In any case, I like your approach - just suggest it to Alex and let him use it.

Comment: Yes, completely agree, it's just something I forget about for some reason. I guess i haven't ever needed to use it in the real world so it hasn't sunk in.